# Where are Authentication Credentials for Canon Image Runner Advanced 4245 Printer

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, printing, cups-lpd

My office has a Canon Image Runner Advanced 4245 Printer, I am trying to set up printing to. I know the IP address, host name, port and my user credentials (username,and password). My OS is Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I also have another machine with Unity.

I found the appropriate PPD file for the printer, and installed, but I see no place to insert my credentials. (The PPD files are copyrighted, but redistributable, with license in header.)

I looked all over printer options for a place to insert Authentication credentials, but I cant find that either.

[image]

I went over to the policies section, and clicked on Authenticate, and applied that. At no point, was I asked to authenticate. Nor did I see a place where I could provide Authentications.

[image]

per the suggestions of some google-fu, I looked at

`~$ sudo vim /etc/cups/printers.conf`

for lines containing Authentication. No such lines were present in that file.
I tried using the CUPS interface `http://localhost:631`
but I still don't see where to provide authentication details.

Can someone point me to the place where I can provide Authentication credentials to this printer?  It will work, if I can figure out how to Authenticate.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change a file as shown below, but before type

```
sudo service cups stop
```

`/etc/cups/printers.conf` is the one you need. Underneath the printer

```
# Printer configuration file for ...
# Written by cupsd on ...
<DefaultPrinter canon>
AuthInfoRequired username,password
Info Canon ...
...
```

The `AuthInfoRequired` is the one you need. Add it to the printer you need it for if it is not there.

Type

```
sudo nano /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

Make the changes : replace     "AuthInfoRequired none" with  "AuthInfoRequired username,password" type  [ctrl] [X] then [Y] then [enter] to exit, save and finaly confirm location.

Then  type

```
sudo service cups start
```

and print as usual, just type your user credential and hit save when asked if you want ubuntu to store them.

Comment: It asked me once, for a username and passwd, which I provided. but I might have selected a feature it doesnt have, and it gave me an error. since then, I have tried reinstalling, and reconfiguring, but it never asks me for a password. That would be ok, but it doesn't print.  ... IDK.

Comment: This worked for me please accept the edit of the post